# Movie about people social engineering their way into a building as part of a heist

Tags: identify-this-movie

I recall this scene from a widely-released movie in the U.S.

The characters were attempting a heist of a well-secured building. One character pretended to be a package delivery man and made a scene at the security desk by attempting to deliver a package that wasn't on the manifest, shouting that he didn't want to lose his job if they refused it and angrily showing them the delivery on his "list" in response to their objections. Meanwhile, his accomplice walked up to the security gate carrying a fake birthday cake (containing various items needed for the heist) and shouted for the guard to "press the [expletive] buzzer" because he had to deliver the cake to a birthday party that was starting in five minutes.

Can anyone help me identify which movie this was from?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a scene from **Sneakers** (1992).  River Phoenix played the package delivery man, and Robert Redford was holding the cake and balloons. They are trying to get up to a hotel room where a foreign scientist has a "black box" on his desk that can either encrypt or decrypt codes. The scene is below.